# Problema com login no laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

Tenho um projecto que consiste numa administração.

O que estou a fazer é o login, eu já criei a tabela e inseri um utilizador com password no modo `Hash` do Laravel.

Tenho o sistema que aparentemente funciona,  o que acontece é que quando tento fazer login da sempre erro de dados errados e eu estou a meter os dados correctos `username` e `password` que criei na tabela.

Podem me ajudar a descobrir o problema?

**Controller**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Redirect;
use Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function showLogin ()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return Redirect::to('/admin');
        }
        return view('admin/login');
    } 

    public function postLogin()
    {
        $data = [
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'passwd' => Input::get('password')
        ];

        if (Auth::attempt($data)) {
            return Redirect::intended('admin');
        }

        return Redirect::back()->with('error_message', 'Dados Incorrectos')->withInput();
    }

    public function logOut()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('admin/login')->with('error_message', 'Logged out correctly');
    }
}
```

Comment: Caro Cesar deveria ser pelo campo email e não pelo username como descrito na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users), caro que existem outros meios de autenticação, por exemplo, pela instância da classe `User`, mas, não é o seu caso.

Comment: Pronto. Eu editei a resposta é a segunda opção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse é o código padrão da [documentação de autenticação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users), perceba que é o campo `email` e `password`, no seu caso está usando outro campo, esse é o problema.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
     // Authentication passed...
     return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}
```

Esse é o modo básico, mas, existe um modo pela instância do usuário, ***exemplo***:

```
public function postLogin()
{

    $username = Input::get('username');
    $passwd   = Input::get('password');

    $user = User::where('username', $username)
        ->first();

    if ($user && Hash::check($passwd, $user->passwd))
    {
        Auth::login($user);
        return Redirect::intended('admin');     
    }

    return Redirect::back()->with('error_message', 'Dados Incorrectos')->withInput();
}
```

é também uma forma válida. A segunda forma consiste em buscar o `User` pelo campo `username`, se retornou um usuário, verificar se a senha corresponde com o `Hash::check` e se passou por tudo isso utilizar a instância dessa classe `Auth::login($user)` para autenticar, e isso funciona parecido com a primeira só que primeira faz tudo isso de forma transparente ao desenvolvedor com os seus campos particulares.

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users)
- [Manually Authenticating Users - Other Authentication Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users)
- [Hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/hashing#basic-usage)

Comment: Mas eu quero usar o campo username que e o que existe na minha tabela e nao email como faco

Comment: Vou propor a solução @CésarSousa ... 2 minutos

Comment: da este erro Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Comment: Faltou algumas chaves @CésarSousa olha agora

Comment: ja testei e funciona certinho pode explicar o que fiz para eu perceber

Comment: @CésarSousa ta editado e a explicação na resposta.

Comment: Obrigado por todo

Comment: Uma coisa estava aqui a testar o  meu logout que tinha feito mas agora ele dame um erro a dizer que nao existe a coluna remember_token na minha tabela como resolvo isto

Comment: Tem como você abrir um novo questionamento @CésarSousa, é assim a pratica do site! coloque as novas informações nela.

Answer (score 0):

Você esta comparando a `string` SEM hash com a string COM hash.

```
$data = [
  'username' => Input::get('username'),
  'passwd' => Input::get('password')
];
```

Use com o Hash:

```
$data = [
  'username' => Input::get('username'),
  'passwd' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
];
```

Comment: Não é esse o problema, é o `email` que ele deveria usar, o `Hash:make` só utilizado para gravar na conferencia do método `attempt` ele já  faz isso **automáticamente**.

Comment: reformule sua pergunta já que você sabe onde é o erro.

Comment: não sou eu que estou com problema, só estou apontando o que ele deveria fazer inclusive crie uma resposta.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic desculpe, não havia percebido que a pergunta não é sua! rs

Comment: sem problemas!.